# How am I supposed to implement this part of the LMS algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, signal-processing

Say I have a $1000$ point data set time series **u** and I'm trying to implement the least mean squares filter on it for some **d(n)**:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter
 (Specifically referring to the LMS algorithm summary section)

If the algorithm says to calculate $\textbf{u[n]} = [u[n], u[n-1], ..., u[n-p+1]] \text{ for each } n = 0, 1, ...$

How am I supposed to handle this?  Do I wrap around in the cases where $n-k < 0$ (as in $x[-1]$ = $x[$last point$]$), or do I set them all to 0?

Comment: Can you simply make sure $n \geq p$ before applying the filter? That is, wait until you have at least $p$ samples before you start filtering?

Comment: Set them to zero unless you have some a priori knowledge otherwise.